# Global dictionary has change value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the sample code below:

```
A = None       
class App(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        global A
        A = a   
a = {'x': 1}
print(A)  # None

App(a)
print(A)  # {'x': 1}

a['x'] = 2
print(A)  # {'x': 2} # value change if dictionary

a = 2
print(A)  # {'x': 2} # value not change
```

But I don't know why **global A** has been change value? Help me know this please

Comment: Just as saying `print(a)` prints the object itself instead of printing the string `a`, `A = a` assigns `A` to the object itself, not the the name `a`.  `A` is the same as `a` just because they refer to the same object.  When you use `a['x'] = 2`, you are doing an operation on the object.  Since `A` refers to the same object, the changes are visible when you print `A`.  When you say `a = 2`, `a` now refers to a different object.  It is not modifying the object that it used to refer to, so the changes are not visible in `A`.

Comment: @zondo nice, I think here is the answer what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the line `global A` in your class method. This makes sure that the variable `A` referred there is the same as the global `A` you define in the first line. If you were to leave out that statement, a new local variable `A` would have been defined in the function.

Once you run the class method, `A` now references `a`. So all changes to `a` apply to `A` as well.

In the very last line you change the type of the variable `a` and it's value. `A` will now lose its binding to `a`. See this answer for the explanation: ["if you rebind the reference in the method, the outer scope will know nothing about it, and after you're done, the outer reference will still point at the original object."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: I deliberately use global variable. I just do not understand why re-assign "a" dictionary to alter the "A"